# Please explain this output

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
print ("Hello" , "World")
```

The output is : ('Hello' , 'World'). Why is it not just Hello World?
(I am very new to python. Started learning 3 weeks ago.)

Comment: You are printing a tuple.

Comment: print("hello", "world") will print `hello, world`. But print ('hello', 'world') is actually printing a tupple. `('hello', 'world')`

Comment: @VikashSingh Nope. Not at all.

Comment: @VikashSingh Incorrect. In python2, either of those will print the tuple. In python3, either will print the string. In other words, they are syntactically equivalent.

Comment: Read python2.7 `print` and data type`tuple`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python 2.7 we have

```
print('hello', 'world')
print ('hello', 'world')
print ('hello , world')
```

output:

```
('hello', 'world')
('hello', 'world')
hello , world
```

Print is a statement. Which passes the parameter just like that. So if we have one object inside the parenthesis it works fine. But if there are multiple objects inside the parenthesis they get passed as a tuple object. And A tuple will get printed like a tuple.

Basically

```
print('a', 'b')
```

is same as

```
a = ('a', 'b')
print(a)
# or
print a

# output : ('a', 'b')
```

And that's what you would expect.

On the other hand in python 3 Print is a function. So you have to call it.
Basically now 'hello', 'world' is not a tuple. Rather multiple arguments being passed separately to print function.

```
print('hello', 'world')
```

output:

```
hello world
```

To achieve the same effect in 3.5 we will have to do this

```
print(('hello', 'world'))
```

output:

```
('hello', 'world')
```

You can read up more here: http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_2_3_key_diff.html

Comment: If you really want to give a full answer a question this basic, at least have the decency to explain the difference between a print statement and a print function.

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the few non-backwards compatible changes between Python3 and Python2.

In Python2, `print` was a statement. In Python3 it was converted to a function call. Statements in Python are things like this:

```
x = 3
import this
from math import pi
```

Function calls look like this:

```
some_list.sort()
counter.most_common()
```

The parenthesis `()` are what means "call this thing".

If you're learning Python you [*should* learn with Python3](https://eev.ee/blog/2016/07/31/python-faq-why-should-i-use-python-3/), but if you can't install that or you don't want to for whatever reason, you can get this behavior in Python2 with the `__future__` import:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print('the future', 'looks better')
the future looks better
```

If it's in a Python script it must be the first non-comment line in the file, but in the repl (interactive interpreter, the thing with the `>>>` prompt), you can do the import at any time.

Answer (score -3):

Because you are trying to use print in python 2.7, pythont hinks that you are asking it to print a tuple.  To output just hello world in python 2.7, you can do something like:

```
print "Hello", "World" # without the parentheses!
```

Or

```
print "%s %s" % ("Hello", "World")
```

Or even

```
from __future__ import print_function
print("Hello", "World")
```

If you were or will be using python 3 instead of python 2, you already have the print function available without the special import.  If you want to read more about tuples, I would recommend that you look at tuples in this [link](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)

Comment: Try posting some code that would _actually_ work for OPs question.  Then the answer would be more valuable.